# Jasmine tests in Livescript: "it" keyword conflict

Tags: livescript

I'm trying to port some Jasmine tests from javascript to LiveScript. One of Jasmine's functions is `it`. Here's an example:

```
(function(){
  describe("The selling page", function() {
    // bla bla
    it("should display cards.", function() {
        expect(selectedCards.count()).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

So, I tried this in LiveScript:

```
do !->
  describe "the selling page " !->
   it "should display cards" !->
       expect (selectedCards.count()).toEqual("")
```

Which compiles to this:

```
// Generated by LiveScript 1.3.1
(function(){
   describe("the selling page ", function(it){ // <--- note the "it"
     it("should display cards", function(){
     expect(browser.getTitle().toEqual(""));
});
});
})();
```

You notice that the second function takes the "it" as an argument. I didn't find the livescript doc about this but I understand it's a feature  (if I replace the `it` function by something else it's all fine. That makes me confident I'm not partially applying a function).

However, I need the `it` function and I don't want it as an argument. How can I write this snippet then ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use (...) in describe to avoid adding extra params

Like that:

```
do !->
  describe "the selling page", (...) !->
   it "should display cards" !->
       expect (selectedCards.count()).toEqual("")
```

Comment: That works, thanks. mmh… so we don't use splats here to "call the function with the arguments of the current function". Are we doing destructuring of arguments here ?

Comment: @Ehvince it's an anonymous splat, which doesn't bind anything

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind aliasing `it` for something else, you can also do this:

```
that = it

do !->
  describe "the selling page " !->
   that "should display cards" !->
       expect selectedCards.count! .to-equal ''
```

When `it` is not in a function, it is treated as global `it`.